# PLS-00363 Input parameter, value assignment

Tags: sql, plsql

I have problem to add variable value as input parameter to procedure upd_users.

```
  PROCEDURE reset_pass (in_row IN users%ROWTYPE)
  IS
  l_random_pass varchar2(4000);
  BEGIN
  SELECT DBMS_RANDOM.string('x',10) INTO l_random_pass FROM DUAL;
  in_row.password  := l_random_pass;
  
  account_api.upd_users( table_row => in_row );
  END reset_pass;
```

When I try to complile I get `PLS-00363: expression 'in_row.password' cannot be used as an assignment target`

I can't assign value for input parameter, but procedure upd_users has also %ROWTYPE parameter.
And I can't add more then one value. Another input value in call reset_pass, should be id for user

EDIT: upd_users procedure:

```
PROCEDURE upd_users (
    table_row    IN   users%rowtype
) IS
BEGIN     
    UPDATE users
    SET
        row = table_row
    WHERE
        id = table_row.id;         
END upd_users;
```

Comment: Your error message says "in_rows"  there is no variable called "in_rows".  Assuming that is a typo?  Please also edit the question and show the definition of account_api.upd_users

Comment: I edited code. It was a mistake when I copied the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should convert IN parameter to IN OUT

```
 PROCEDURE reset_pass (in_row IN OUT users%ROWTYPE)
```

Alternate method is, to take a local record object in-case you can not modify it to IN OUT.

```
PROCEDURE reset_pass (in_row IN users%ROWTYPE)
  IS
  l_random_pass varchar2(4000);
  in_row_local users%ROWTYPE;
  BEGIN
  in_row_local := in_row;
  SELECT DBMS_RANDOM.string('x',10) INTO l_random_pass FROM DUAL;
  in_row_local.password  := l_random_pass;
  
  account_api.upd_users( table_row => in_row_local );
  END reset_pass;
```

Comment: I tried this, but when I call procedure with id as parameter I got: `PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'RESET_PASS'`

Comment: try the alternate method